# Get ONLY panel from other forms to mdi containter

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, panel, mdi

I'm creating an Inventory system and what I want to happen is when I click the buttons the content will change but not the header and navigation panel.

WHAT I ALREADY TRIED:
-created panels and used panel.show()/panel.hide() (GETS out of control when I have created many panels and put it in same position as others, when I hide one, all of them is hidden.)

now my main form is a MDI container and I created new forms that contains ONLY the panels that I will be needing. I wanted to know if there's any way that I could get ONLY the panel from other form to the MDI container.

[this is my MDI form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZAXc.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Load Form inside panel other form in win app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962341/how-to-load-form-inside-panel-other-form-in-win-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show your forms in panel. like

```
  panel1.Controls.Add(Form1);
```