# How load a form into another form's panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form called frmTest1 with a splitcontainer with two panels. Panel 2 should load many forms one at a time. It works fine for the first form, but the second form cant then load a third form into panel 2 of frmTest1.

Here is stripped frmTest 1 code:

```
namespace Project1
{
public partial class frmMain3 : Form
{
    public frmMain3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnShowTest1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showScreen(new frmTest1());
    }

    public void showScreen(Control ctl)
    {
        while (splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Count > 0)
            splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls[0].Dispose();

        if (ctl is Form)
        {
            var frm = ctl as Form;
            frm.TopLevel = false;
            frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            frm.Visible = true;
        }
        ctl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(ctl);
    }
}
}
```

The second form's code is below:

```
namespace Project1
{
public partial class frmTest1 : Form
{
    public frmTest1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnShowTest4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frmMain3 main = new frmMain3();
        main.showScreen(new frmTest4()); //Nothing shows
    }
}
}
```

From the research I have done it seems the solution is to use a usercontrol but having never used it before, I am struggling. Can someone please show me how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Load Form inside panel other form in win app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962341/how-to-load-form-inside-panel-other-form-in-win-app)

Comment: *"but having never used it before"* - is not a good excuse for not trying. Try. Maybe you will succeed on the first attempt. If not - you have a good (better than current) question and a reason to ask it on SO.

Comment: I have spent two days stuck on this already, thats why I asked

Comment: You need to use an instance of the for.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: The notes here may be interesting: [Auto-resize multiple windows forms being rendered on panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476266/7444103).

Comment: Simple mistake, add `main.Show();` to the Click event handler.

Comment: Do not add forms to controls. It is meant to be the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use a UserControl. Just change the base class of frmMain3 to "UserControl" and delete the whole "if (ctl is Form)"-part from showScreen().